# What is the difference between ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET Core 6.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My understanding was that .NET will no longer produce .NET core versions, but rather MVC 5 is the next evolution of the .net core 3 onwards.

However I am now seeing there is MVC 5, MVC 6, and also .net core 6. What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 3):

**No**, I think you're wrong. But that's partly due to rather confusing Microsoft marketing, I agree...

Microsoft will **not produce any more versions** of the **full, classic** .NET framework - that ends with .NET 4.8. ASP.NET MVC 5 was built on top of .NET 4.x

---

The **Core** product line **IS** the future for now. For marketing reasons, they're no longer called ".NET Core" - but it's really

.NET Core 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1

---> then .NET 5, now .NET 6, next year .NET 7 and then .NET 8 - and those are **really** ".NET Core" versions.

The web framework is still called **ASP.NET Core 6.0** and the MVC framework is **ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC** (and there's also ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API).

Comment: So .NET 6 is .NET core 6.0 and the same as ASP.NET Core 6.0?

Comment: **.NET 6** "contains" ASP.NET Core 6, ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, Entity Framework Core 6 and many more components - yes. And for techies - this should really be called .NET Core 6 - but the marketing department decided to drop the "Core" - for whatever obscure reasons........